# clojure loop see values

Tags: loops, debugging, clojure

When using [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) there is the [`reductions`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions) function to see the list of successive reductions. Is there something similar to debug a [`loop`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) in Clojure ?

Comment: Does it have to return a lazy sequence like `reductions` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@progo is right, you can always add another accumulator, but if you don't really want to do it every time, you could make some utility macro doing that for you, while being semantically equal to the default `loop/recur` (i am thinking of pair of `loop+/recur+` (the latter would be used implicitly):

```
(defmacro recur+ [& args]
  (let [names (repeatedly (count args) gensym)]
    `(let ~(vec (interleave names args))
       (recur ~@names (conj ~'&loop-history [~@names])))))

(defmacro loop+ [bindings & body]
  (let [val-names (repeatedly (/ (count bindings) 2) gensym)
        vals (take-nth 2 (rest bindings))
        binding-lefts (take-nth 2 bindings)]
    `(let [~@(interleave val-names vals)]
       (loop [~@(interleave binding-lefts val-names)
              ~'&loop-history [~(vec val-names)]]
         ~@(clojure.walk/postwalk-replace
            {'recur 'recur+
             'loop 'loop+}
            body)))))
```

as you can see, `loop+` introduces the implicit value `&loop-history`, and replaces all the inner `loop`s and `recur`s with `loop+` and `recur+`, while `recur+` adds this implicit var to the `recur` call (the part with `val-names`, `vals` and `binging-lefts` is essential to avoid the double evaluation of the forms passed to the `loop+`).

so, imagine you have some loop like this:

```
user> (loop [a 1 b 2]
        (if (<= b 10)
          (recur a (inc b))
          (str a " " b)))
"1 11"
```

to use the new loop just call loop+ instead of loop:

```
user> (loop+ [a 1 b 2]
        (if (<= b 10)
          (recur a (inc b))
          (str a " " b)))
"1 11"
```

it is expanded into the following:

```
(let*
  [G__20054 1 G__20055 2]
  (loop*
    [a G__20054 b G__20055 &loop-history [[G__20054 G__20055]]]
    (if (<= b 10)
      (let*
        [G__20056 a G__20057 (inc b)]
        (recur
          G__20056
          G__20057
          (conj &loop-history [G__20056 G__20057])))
      (str a " " b))))
```

now `&loop-history` is totally accessible anywhere inside loop+:

```
user> (loop+ [a 1 b 2]
        (if (<= b 10)
          (do
            (println "history length: " (count &loop-history)
                     "last item: " (last &loop-history))
            (recur a (inc b)))
          {:result (str a " " b)
           :history &loop-history}))

;; history length:  1 last item:  [1 2]
;; history length:  2 last item:  [1 3]
;; history length:  3 last item:  [1 4]
;; history length:  4 last item:  [1 5]
;; history length:  5 last item:  [1 6]
;; history length:  6 last item:  [1 7]
;; history length:  7 last item:  [1 8]
;; history length:  8 last item:  [1 9]
;; history length:  9 last item:  [1 10]
;; {:result "1 11", :history [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [1 8] [1 9] [1 10] [1 11]]}
```

notice, that it also introduces `&loop-history` for inner loops, without the need to change the source code:

```
user> (loop+ [a 1 b 2]
        (if (<= b 10)
          (do (println :outer-hist &loop-history)
              (recur a (inc b)))
          (loop [a a]
            (if (>= a -4)
              (do (println :inner-hist &loop-history)
                  (recur (dec a)))
              (str a b)))))

:outer-hist [[1 2]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [1 8]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [1 8] [1 9]]
:outer-hist [[1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [1 8] [1 9] [1 10]]
:inner-hist [[1]]
:inner-hist [[1] [0]]
:inner-hist [[1] [0] [-1]]
:inner-hist [[1] [0] [-1] [-2]]
:inner-hist [[1] [0] [-1] [-2] [-3]]
:inner-hist [[1] [0] [-1] [-2] [-3] [-4]]
"-511"
```

Answer (score 2):

`loop`/`recur` is more imperative than `reductions`; you may very well just insert your own logging to the loop body yourself, or maintain an atom list of values, or most functionally, introduce an(other) accumulator to the loop arguments.